# Dynamically update div size on resize

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to set a height in px on my container when the size updates. I can display the size as text, and it updates when my container resizes.
However, the height attribute on my container does not update.

Js:

```
setup() {
    const el = ref(null);
    const { height, width } = useElementSize(el);

    return {height, width, el,}
}
```

Html:

```
{{ height }}
<div>
  :style="{ height: `${height}px` }"
  ref="el"
>
Resizeable items whoopwhoop
</div>
```

In this case my `{{ height }}` updates if I remove the :style attribute, but it says 0px with the :style attribute. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to return `el` ?

Comment: @StefanoNepa Yes

Comment: This seems weird. Can you reproduce your problem on stackblitz.com or some online tools?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what `useElementSize` is.

but if you try this:

```html
<script setup>
import { ref , computed} from 'vue'
const el = ref(null);
  
const height = ref(100);
const width = ref(200);
  
  const dynamicStyle = computed(()=>{
    return {
      height: height.value + "px",
      width: width.value + "px"
    }
  })
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="height" type="number" />
    <input v-model="width" type="number" />
    <div class="resizable"
      :style="dynamicStyle"
      ref="el"
    >
     {{dynamicStyle}}
    </div>  
  </div>
</template>

<style>
  .resizable{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: royalblue;
  }
</style>
```

you can modify the size of the element by changing the inputs values.

Here is the [Example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9Ustu4zAM/BVClybY2O7u0ZsU2G/Yqy5+MIlavaBHul7D/15KstugQHuSqBlyqCFn9sfa+haRtezoBydsAI8h2ieuhbLGBZjB4RkOMBhlY8BxgbMzCh4o6YHrwWgfACWcEm2no5T731wDbNAVxeUaVvjn42NCC/IqxnBdgV8FSGlASgkeJ90pMfwNk0RibfK73f70NCcaUGaITsMawarVrmd962RE+AGc2X+cHTZW1m3L8YlTKEs6lj3Xx6ZYQmZQEFBZ2QWkCOA4ilu+0FVo6gxulTIjyhNnRZ4zCJNFinVUPTqKm68yci/fJZAaDLLznlCHXvzveolbvwCtTy4Rdm/aB0wOE4Zye1mrwjzf85f8bxJr0t/KKMo9OXH3ewqzXi5Tv7ezjmEUnohTC0JLobHqpRle8mwB+m54uTgT9VgNRhrXgjNTJ3uaQWZQB+R5rs0OrCxgpTpbP3ujaUWzBF8Bz1m7zZ4zWscUk/shWN82jT8PabGffW3cpaFb7aIOQmGNXlW9M68eHRUuppDywpY3fBgDvg==) above.

Comment: Seems to give the same output when I rewrite it to that setup. Without the :style it works, with the :style it always gives back 0px.